# Change style to HSlider - Haxeui

Tags: haxe, haxeui

Is possibile to change the Hslider in haxe? (via xml or programmatically, it's the same for me)

i would like to change the bar color, i saw some tutorials for as3 but it seems that they don't work with haxe (like skinclass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change every component using the styles and building style rules. Heres an example in the layout builder:

http://haxeui.org/try.jsp?layoutId=R5BM89r

In this example only the specific `HSlider` is selected by id (ie, `#mySlider`), if you wanted to change all sliders you could specify the class instead of the id (ie, `HSlider`).

More info here: http://haxeui.org/wiki/en/Styling.

One thing that is sorely missing (which i hope to rectify soon) is what components specific components contain, ie, what sub components (children) the `HSlider` contains (as an example). This would go a long way to help custom styling. I hope to get this sorted soon.

Comment: wow that's amazing, the real problem is that i can't find this things in the documentation, i couldn't even imagine that #background could stand for the element's background >.<. You're doing a great, awesome job anyway!

Comment: Indeed. The docs for this are really lacking. I keep meaning to force myself to do something about that, but keep getting distracted. At the very least i need to document what child components a component contains (for styling and general understanding). Anyways, glad that fixed your specific issue. Bear with me on the docs! :)